# How to make an ordered list second level with continuing points?

Tags: html, html-lists

I want to make an unordered list the has an ordered second level that continues counting it's points. I know I can do it with <ol start="*Previous number+1*"> but is it possible to continue list automatically? Below is an example as well as example in the picture.

1. First
   a. first
   b. second
2. Second
   c. third

This is how I've done it:

```
<ul>
<li>ASV:<br/><ol type="I">
    <li>HP</li><li>Dell</li><li>Apple</li><li>Google</li><li>Microsoft</li><li>EVGA Corporation</li><li>Maingear</li><li>Origin PC</li><li>Velocity Micro</li><li>Vizio</li></ol>
</li>
<li>Ķīna:<br/><ol type="I" start="11">
    <li>Lenovo</li><li>Huawei</li><li>Founder</li><li>Hasee</li><li>Lemote</li></ol>
</li>
<li>Japāna:<br/><ol type="I" start="16">
    <li>Panasonic</li><li>Sharp</li><li>Toshiba</li><li>VAIO</li>
</ol></li>
<li>Taivāna:<br/><ol type="I" start="20">
    <li>Acer</li><li>Asus</li><li>Clevo</li><li>Gigabyte Technology</li><li>Via</li>
</ol></li>
```

I'm just a beginner so I'm sorry if the format isn't the greatest.
[This is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWJdd.png)

Comment: can you share the code you have tried and what isn't working

Comment: I'll update the post

Comment: don't you want send any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with css Counter :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counters

sample code:

```css
ul#my-list { 
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: nRef; 
  counter-reset: aRef; 
  }
ul#my-list>li        { counter-increment: nRef; }
ul#my-list>li:before { content: counter(nRef) '. '; }

ul#my-list>li>ul           { list-style: none; }
ul#my-list>li>ul>li        { counter-increment: aRef; }
ul#my-list>li>ul>li:before { content: counter(aRef, lower-alpha) '. '; }
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>ASV: 
    <ul>
      <li>HP</li><li>Dell</li><li>Apple</li><li>Google</li>
      <li>Microsoft</li><li>EVGA Corporation</li><li>Maingear</li>
      <li>Origin PC</li><li>Velocity Micro</li><li>Vizio</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Ķīna: 
    <ul>
      <li>Lenovo</li><li>Huawei</li><li>Founder</li>
      <li>Hasee</li><li>Lemote</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Japāna: 
    <ul>
      <li>Panasonic</li><li>Sharp</li><li>Toshiba</li><li>VAIO</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Taivāna: 
    <ul>
      <li>Acer</li><li>Asus</li><li>Clevo</li>
      <li>Gigabyte Technology</li><li>Via</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```